# bootstrap 4 - form in modal, div not being displayed on select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, laravel, bootstrap-4

In a Laravel app I've got a form in a modal that on load shows just one select menu. When a user makes a selection a div needs to appear below with another select of subsequent options. I've tried a number of approaches from SO and Code Pen but can't seem to make the subsequent divs display. The code below is where I've finally ended up. Any help would be appreciated.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.scopes').hide();
        $('#programSelect').change(function () {
            $('.scopes').hide();
            $('#'+$(this).val()).show();
    })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="programSelect">Select Program</label>
    <span class="bg-danger">{{ $errors->first('program') }}</span>
    <select id="programSelect" class="form-control custom-select program-select" name="program">
        <option></option>
        @foreach($program as $program)
            <option value="{{ $program->id }}">{{ $program->abbr }}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
</div>

<div class="form-group scopes nop" id="nop">
    <label for="nopselect">Select NOP Scope</label>
    <span class="bg-danger">{{ $errors->first('nopselect') }}</span>
    <select name="scope_id" class="form-control custom-select" id="nopselect">
        <option selected></option>
        <option value="1">Crops</option>
        <option value="2">Livestock</option>
        <option value="3">Handling</option>
        <option value="4">Wild Crops</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group scopes eu" id="eu">
    <label for="euselect">Select EU Scope</label>
    <span class="bg-danger">{{ $errors->first('euselect') }}</span>
    <select name="scope_id" class="form-control custom-select" id="euselect">
        <option selected></option>
        <option value="5">Unprocessed Plant Products</option>
        <option value="6">Livestock</option>
        <option value="7">Handling</option>
        <option value="8">Feed</option>
        <option value="9">Seed</option>
        <option value="10">Aquaculture</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group scopes jpexport" id="jpexport">
    <label for="jpexportselect">Select JP Export Scope</label>
    <span class="bg-danger">{{ $errors->first('jpexportselect') }}</span>
    <select name="scope_id" class="form-control custom-select" id="jpexportselect">
        <option selected></option>
        <option value="27">Crops</option>
        <option value="28">Handling</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group scopes gots" id="gots">
    <label for="gotsselect">Select GOTS Scope</label>
    <span class="bg-danger">{{ $errors->first('gotsselect') }}</span>
    <select name="scope_id" class="form-control custom-select" id="gotsselect">
        <option selected></option>
        <option value="17">Dry</option>
        <option value="18">Wet</option>
        <option value="19">Trading</option>
        <option value="20">Inputs</option>

    </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group scopes te" id="te">
    <label for="teselect">Select TE Scope</label>
    <span class="bg-danger">{{ $errors->first('teselect') }}</span>
    <select name="scope_id" class="form-control custom-select" id="teselect">
        <option selected></option>
        <option value="25">OE</option>
        <option value="26">OCS</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group scopes cor" id="cor">
    <label for="corselect">Select COR Scope</label>
    <span class="bg-danger">{{ $errors->first('corselect') }}</span>
    <select name="scope_id" class="form-control custom-select" id="corselect">
        <option selected></option>
        <option value="29">Crops</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group scopes jas" id="jas">
    <label for="jasselect">Select JAS Scope</label>
    <span class="bg-danger">{{ $errors->first('jasselect') }}</span>
    <select name="scope_id" class="form-control custom-select" id="jasselect">
        <option selected></option>
        <option value="11">Crops</option>
        <option value="12">Handling</option>
        <option value="13">Repack Crops</option>
        <option value="14">Repack Food</option>
        <option value="15">Feed</option>
        <option value="16">Repack Feed</option>
        <option value="30">Wild Harvest</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group scopes npop" id="npop">
    <label for="npopselect">Select NPOP Scope</label>
    <span class="bg-danger">{{ $errors->first('npopselect') }}</span>
    <select name="scope_id" class="form-control custom-select" id="npopselect">
        <option selected></option>
        <option value="21">Crops</option>
        <option value="22">Livestock</option>
        <option value="23">Processing</option>
        <option value="24">Trading</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: At a glance, everything looks ok, but having `.blade` code kinda messes with the snippet. Add some logging into your JS; make sure your `.change()` function is being called, and verify the contents of `$(this).val()` to ensure it matches an `id="..."` on the page. Oh, and make sure you don't have any console errors.

Comment: Did you tried `if($('#programSelect option:selected').attr('selected', 'selected')){ $('.scopes').hide();$('#'+$(this).val()).show();}` ?